# phabricator on redhat's openshift

Tags: php, openshift, phabricator

I installed phabricator on openshift using a quickstart from github
https://github.com/CodeBlock/phabricator-openshift-quickstart

I got it running up fine, but I now have two issues:

1.) A setup issue that says apc.stat is enabled and that must be disabled in 
/var/lib/openshift/my-user-hash/php/configuration/etc/php.ini

however I cannot access that with sudo command(sudo permission denied), even if I open it normally, I didn't find any apc.stat settings in the php.ini

2.) I can't figure out how set the local path for tracking repositories for diffusion. It says
I must give a path which should be read-writable by phabricator, I tried to give the persistent storage location ..data/ , but it gives me an exception as follows :

Unhandled Exception ("CommandException")
Command failed with error #1!

COMMAND
(cd '../data/' && HOME='/var/lib/openshift/my-user-hash/app-root/runtime/repo/phabricator/support/empty/' git cat-file --batch)

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
sh: line 0: cd: ../data/: No such file or directory

how do I fix this?

Comment: For 1), we're working on exposing php.ini or some parameters.  See [this forum thread](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/can-not-edit-the-phpini#comment-33961) for more details on how we went back and forth on the issue and the result is [this Trello story](https://trello.com/c/fSWvzkPM)

Comment: For 2), try using the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR env variable rather than a relative path.

Comment: @NamDuong do you mean that I should use $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR in the local path input field in the web interface(UI) settings, I already tried that and it gave the same error

Comment: Out of interest, what gear size did you have to use to get a decent level of performance?

Comment: @muttonUp I used the small gear, the only thing available for a free account. I was just testing to see if openshift can be used to setup phabricator. I didn't setup any of the advanced features like diffusion or arcanist, so can't give any reliable performance metrics there.

Answer (score 1):

1) According to Num Duong answer, it seems like u currently could not resolve this issue, probably u should wait for openshift `php.ini`  permissions policy changes.
Anyway this is minor non blocking issue.

2) Modify [config file](https://github.com/CodeBlock/phabricator-openshift-quickstart/blob/master/misc/myconfig.conf.php.dist) and re-deploy to openshift.
Look for available phabricator options [here](https://github.com/facebook/phabricator/blob/master/conf/default.conf.php)

U need smth like this: `'repository.default-local-path' => getenv('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'),`

P.S. Anyway there is one particular issue with phabricator on openshift that possibly never got resolved: cloning git repositories from OpenShift instances into Phabricator do not
work by SSH, due to permissions regarding the ssh configuration.